# How "Login With Facebook" Mechanism work in Android to communicate with other app?

Tags: android, facebook

I had developed **4 Apps**.

1. Main App
2. App Alpha
3. App Beta
4. App Gama

All 4 Apps have same **Login with email** option, and user can login with **same email address and password** like Gmail, Google Keep and Google Photos do.

So, I want to make **Login with Main App** Options, So if user is signed in Main App in same device, when they click from other app's **Login With Main App** button, other app should communicate with Main App and get token from thek and do autologin for.[Same as FB messenger and FB Main app login functionality]

So How its possible in Android ?
Deeplink ? Shared Preference ? Or Any other technique ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly. Its because of the Facebook Login feature. If you already logged in with Facebook or connect that app to it. It is automatically logging in as long as the Facebook session on your phone is still active. Which on the phone it can last theoretically indefinitely until server maintenance in which is where they usually ask you to change your password.

So how does it log in? Built in framework to allow it to be done.

Comment: i just edited my questions, hope you understood correctly.